How this sad movie with two sisters is called? 2007 or before
I would like to identify a movie that appeared in 2006/2007. By now, I just remember these scenes (may not be in order).

Two girls try to find in a yellow pages located in a drug store their dad's  address.
They have to run from the mentioned drug store because the druggist seemed to be calling the police.
An old green VW rabbit-like car with two workers went out of a factory.
The girls might have confused that car with his father's.
They went to the house and find his new wife and a big black dog.
They finally found his father but he refuses to give money and call his former wife a "b|tch".
The little girl found a reptile but her sister said she should release it.
They ran out of money and had to call someone to pick them up.
A guy and the girl's mother picked them. Just before the ending the former factory appears.

Some facts about the movie I saw.

One of the girls was "dark" (like Krysten Ritter's Jessica Jones).
The other girl seemed like Dakota Fanning in "War of the worlds".
The movie was presented in spring 2006 or 2007 in the mexican A&E
channel.

